# Parsing weekday names displays always "Monday" using d3.time.format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 v3.x, I would like to use d3.time.format for parsing the weekday names and then translating them with the locale.timeFormat method.

This is an example of translation into Catalan:

```
var LOCALES = {
en: d3.locale({days:["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]}),
ca: d3.locale({days:['Diumenge', 'Dilluns', 'Dimarts', 
'Dimecres','Dijous','Divendres', 'Dissabte'"]})
};

var locale = LOCALES["ca"];
var weekdayParser = locale.timeFormat("%A");

var daysOfTheWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

for(var i=0; i<daysOfTheWeek.length; i++){ 
daysOfTheWeek[i] = 
weekdayParser(d3.time.format("%A").parse(daysOfTheWeek[i]));
};
```

Result:

```
daysOftheWeek = ["Dilluns", "Dilluns", "Dilluns", 
"Dilluns", "Dilluns", "Dilluns", "Dilluns"];
```

Is there any mistake in using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for your answer, but it did not provide me the solution. However, you gave me the idea for the solution. I hope that it can be useful for other people, considering this D3 library limitation.

This was my solution:

```
/*
  ##Adding the days of the week to the calendar##
  Only a year and month is needed,
  the different days of the week are added inside the for loop,
  starting by the first day "1" of the month
*/
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
  var weekdayParser1 = d3.time.format("%w"); //parser for day numbers
  var weekdayParser2 = locale.timeFormat("%A"); //parser for day names

  var yourTime = "201704";
  var daysOfTheWeeK = [];

  for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
      //Adding the days of the week according to the parsed Date "yourTime"
      daysOfTheWeeK.push({
          "weekdayNumber": weekdayParser1(parseDate(Number(yourTime+"01")+i+"")),
          "weekdayName": weekdayParser2(parseDate(Number(yourTime+"01")+i+""))
      });
      //Replacing the original order of the week as Sunday = 0 by Sunday = 7 , then Monday = 1 is the first day
      if (daysOfTheWeeK[i].weekdayNumber === "0") {
          daysOfTheWeeK[i].weekdayNumber = "7";
      }
  };
  daysOfTheWeeK.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseFloat(a.weekdayNumber) - parseFloat(b.weekdayNumber);
  });
```

Result:

```
[{
    "weekdayNumber": "1",
    "weekdayName": "Dilluns"
},
{
    "weekdayNumber": "2",
    "weekdayName": "Dimarts"
},
{
    "weekdayNumber": "3",
    "weekdayName": "Dimecres"
},
{
    "weekdayNumber": "4",
    "weekdayName": "Dijous"
},
{
    "weekdayNumber": "5",
    "weekdayName": "Divendres"
},
{
    "weekdayNumber": "6",
    "weekdayName": "Dissabte"
},
{
    "weekdayNumber": "7",
    "weekdayName": "Diumenge"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can pass a day of the week to d3.time.format().parse, it won't do anything. D3 parses dates using pretty much everything *except* day of the week (`%A`,`%a`,`%w`).

This can lead to awkward parsing of time:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%A-%y-%m-%d");
console.log(format(format.parse("Monday-17-05-17"))); // "Wednesday-17-05-17"
```

And, as you note:

```
format = d3.time.format("%A");
console.log(format(format.parse("Wednesday"))); // "Monday"
```

As well as:

```
format = d3.time.format("%a");
console.log(format(format.parse("Wed"))); // "Mon"
```

And:

```
format = d3.time.format("%w");
console.log(format(format.parse("5"))); // "1"
```

Why Monday?

The default time when parsing with d3 is 1900-01-01 0:0:0.000. When parsing a date, these numbers are modified; if modifying only year and month, day remains 1. As parsing the day of the week does not modify any of these numbers, the date remains 1900-01-01, which, as fate has it, was a Dilluns.